# "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" on a line setting a variable to a non-optional value

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm getting the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance" on this line:

`newAlarm.note = note`

inside my Alarm.swift `newAlarm()` method. Here's that method:

```
static func newAlarm(context: NSManagedObjectContext, alarmNumber: Int, timeIntervals: TimeIntervals, note: String, recurrence: RecurrenceOptions) -> Alarm? {

    let startInterval = Alarm.convertToTimeDouble(hour: timeIntervals.hourStartInterval, minute: timeIntervals.minuteStartInterval)
    let endInterval = Alarm.convertToTimeDouble(hour: timeIntervals.hourEndInterval, minute: timeIntervals.minuteEndInterval)

    if endInterval < startInterval {
        os_log("Error: Alarm time endInterval is before startInterval", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)
        return nil
    }
    let newAlarm = Alarm(context: context)
    newAlarm.alarmNumber = alarmNumber
    newAlarm.note = note
    newAlarm.recurrence = recurrence
    newAlarm.notificationUuids = [String]()
    newAlarm.startTimeInterval = startInterval
    newAlarm.endTimeInterval = endInterval

    newAlarm.setNewRandomAlarmTime()

    return newAlarm
}
```

As you can see, note is passed in and is not an optional value. Here is how I declare the Alarm class:

```
class Alarm: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var alarmTime: Double
    @NSManaged var alarmNumber: Int
    @NSManaged var startTimeInterval: Double
    @NSManaged var endTimeInterval: Double
    @NSManaged var note: String
    @NSManaged var notificationUuids: [String]
    @NSManaged var recurrenceIndex: Int
    let NUMBER_OF_ALLOWED_NOTIFICATIONS_CREATED_AT_ONE_TIME = 10

}
```

So the `note` field isn't optional there either. I'm assuming this error is because the note field is blank, which it is, but I can't find online why that would be a problem. In AddAlarmViewController, just before calling `Alarm.newAlarm()`, I have this:

```
guard let noteText = self.noteTextField.text else {
    os_log("Couldn't unwrap noteText in prepare(for:sender:) in AddAlarmViewController", log: OSLog.default, type: .default)
    return
}
```

There's no failure here; the guard statement goes through without failing. Which tells me that the `noteText` variable can't be nil, right? So why am I getting an error on setting this field? I'm not getting this error on the assignment of `alarmNumber`, so I can't imagine why I'd be getting it on the `note` property.

Here's the full error:

```
2018-12-16 20:02:06.592513-0500 RandomAlarm[8528:8134357] -[RandomAlarm.Alarm setNote:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000025b0a00
2018-12-16 20:02:06.598032-0500 RandomAlarm[8528:8134357] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RandomAlarm.Alarm setNote:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000025b0a00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106a591bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001046f6735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106a77f44 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106a5ded6 ___forwarding___ + 1446
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106a5fda8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   RandomAlarm                         0x0000000103d85341 $S11RandomAlarm0B0C03newB07context11alarmNumber13timeIntervals4note10recurrenceACSgSo22NSManagedObjectContextC_SiAA04TimeH0CSSAA17RecurrenceOptionsOtFZ + 721
    6   RandomAlarm                         0x0000000103d7ede1 $S11RandomAlarm03AddB14ViewControllerC7prepare3for6senderySo17UIStoryboardSegueC_ypSgtF + 6209
    7   RandomAlarm                         0x0000000103d7f3fa $S11RandomAlarm03AddB14ViewControllerC7prepare3for6senderySo17UIStoryboardSegueC_ypSgtFTo + 218
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000010934cb24 -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 186
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000010934ca37 -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _perform:] + 83
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000010934a97b -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 157
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001091a9ecb -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00000001088ea95b __45-[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:]_block_invoke + 154
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00000001088ea894 -[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:] + 152
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001091a9ecb -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000108be50bd -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000108be53da -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    17  UIKitCore                           0x0000000108be431e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 583
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00000001091e50a4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2729
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00000001091e67a0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4080
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00000001091c4394 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00000001092995a9 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3054
    22  UIKitCore                           0x000000010929c1cb __handleEventQueueInternal + 5948
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001069be721 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001069bdf93 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001069b863f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001069b7e11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e9151dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00000001091a881d UIApplicationMain + 140
    29  RandomAlarm                         0x0000000103d82587 main + 71
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107c97575 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: This error is unlikely to have anything to do with Optionals (this error comes from the ObjC runtime). What exactly is the error? When it says "unrecognized selector sent to instance" it should also include some indicator of the selector in question. It'll looks something like `-[Alarm setNote:]`, but I'm betting it's not that.

Comment: Thanks, just added the full error to my post.

Comment: The above code didn't generate the above error. As you see in the stack trace, the error is related to operating on RandomAlarm, not Alarm. What is RandomAlarm?

Comment: RandomAlarm is the entire project name

Comment: (First, apologies; that was clearly in the stack and I misread it.) This is very surprising, and suggests that the `Alarm` here isn't actually in sync with the model, or isn't the actual `Alarm` that's being compiled. The point of "unrecognized selector" is that the object at runtime does not implement that method (technically does not respond to the selector which is slightly different, but usually similar). That suggests some mismatch, maybe with your model?

Comment: You were right! I fixed my model, which didn't have a `note` property, and the error went away. Thanks!